# Remover de árvore de busca binaria

Tags: c, árvore, busca-binária

Estudando BST (arvore de busca binaria) não entendi algumas partes do código na função [delete](https://gist.github.com/mycodeschool/9465a188248b624afdbf) do "mycodeschool".

Essa parte do código, mais especificamente:

```
// Case 1:  No child
    if(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) { 
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
    }
//Case 2: One child 
    else if(root->left == NULL) {
        struct Node *temp = root;
        root = root->right;
        delete temp;
    }
```

1. Não entendi porque  em "Case 1"  como o `root` pode receber `NULL` depois de receber o comando `delete`. Eu poderia simplesmente colocar `root=NULL` e só?
2. E também em "Case 2" Quando se deleta `temp`, root também está sendo deletado, não?  já que `temp` possui o mesmo endereço de `root`.
3. E também não entendi a necessidade de deletar já que existe o comando `root=root->right`.
4. E por que em "Case 1" o `delete` vem antes do comando principal `root=NULL` e em "Case 2" o `delete` tá depois do comando principal `root=root->right`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1:** No `Case 1` voçê está removendo um nó que não tem filhos da nem direita nem da esqueda. Remove ele da memória e seta como `null` para que o pai de `root` não aponte para um local da memória que foi 'desalocado';

**2 e 3:** Não, temp possui o endereço do 'antigo' `root` pois `root` agora está apontando para `root->right` . No `Case 2` ele efetua a operação de remoção para nós que tem apenas 1 filho à direita. Quando ele remove `temp` da memória, ele está removendo o antigo `root` pois `root` agora passou a apontar para o nó da direita portanto `temp` aponta para um nó que não está em nenhuma posição da árvore sendo desnecessário deixar ele alocado na memória.

**4:**
No `Case 1` foi respondido no item 1.

No `Case 2`, primeiro ele pega a referencia do conteúdo para onde `root` está apontando e armazena em `temp`, faz `root` apontar para o único nó filho que tem à direita e depois remove o `temp` pois não tem mais necessidade dele alocado na mémoria. Ou seja, ele pega a referencia de `root` antes dele apontar para um novo local, e depois remove o antigo conteúdo de `root`.

[Neste link](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rvore_bin%C3%A1ria_de_busca) tem algumas imagens que vai te auxiliar a entender melhor esse processo de deleção.